# UserForm Option Button Controls Crash Excel After Toggling at Runtime

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem with radio option buttons on a UserForm I have created in excel. When the UserForm is loaded it is defaulted to OptionButton1. If I toggle to OptionButton2 and then toggle back to OptionButton1 excel will be unresponsive and crash when I close the form. If I just toggle to OptionButton2 and close the form or don't toggle them at all, everything will be fine. It only happens if I toggle more than once in a given runtime. Also, the option buttons are on a frame on the userform if that makes any difference.

I have commented out ALL code that is triggered by events attached to the controls and it still happens. Also, the code works perfectly fine in the case that I only toggle the options once. It will crash simply by changing the option to 2 and back to 1 without executing any other code. I have another option button group on the form and I don't have any issues with that group. I can toggle them as many times as I want.

I'm not able to share my actual workbook and have been unsuccessful recreating the problem in an example workbook. I'm not sure what else I can provide that would be of use. If anyone has any suggestions based on my description of the problem, it would be greatly appreciated. I have run out of ideas.

Things I've tried:

- Removing all code associated with the controls
- Changing and removing the group name for the set of option buttons
- deleting the option buttons and remaking them
- changing the names of the option buttons
- copying and pasting the existing working option buttons and renaming them

**EDIT:** I was able to save as on my original workbook and delete everything out except the working and broken option controls. Here is a link to the sample book which is a bare skeleton of my actual workbook:

[Link to workbook example.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5d7hakgFRdWNG44WEhUelVCaUU)

Even with everything gone, the problem still happens. If you open the userform, you can toggle between the "Option A" and "Option B" buttons, but if you try to toggle between "Option 1" and "Option 2" excel will crash when you close the form.

Comment: Seems odd. If you are not calling any excel based stuff in your buttons and just toggling those buttons crash excel. May be it is corrupted, If you are not able to reproduce, just create a new workbook and move on,

Comment: Cannot open your UserForm. Keeps saying `System Error &H80004005`,  then **Out of Memory**.

Comment: Export all the modules, then save the workbook as an .xlsx to discard all your macros, re-import all your modules, then save as .xlsm and recompile.

Comment: @Comintern Thanks for the suggestion, but I get the same error after I did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your User-Form and /or controls are corrupt. In line with what Commitern suggested, instead of full export and recreation, try this:

```
1.Delete your faulty user form. in this case `Test`.    
2.Save and close Excel.    
3. Go to C:\Users\<<yourusername>>\AppData\Local\Temp\VBE    
4. Here delete all the exd files.
5. Re-open workbook add new form, name it `Test` and all option buttons.
```

All works fine.

Remember if you try to add a new user form and rename it as the old one `Test` without saving the file, you will get error.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/244238

Comment: Is there anyway to copy or "fix" the current userform? It took quite a bit of time to build. There are a lot of controls and interactions and would like to avoid rebuilding from scratch if at all possible.

Comment: This does work. I was able to rebuild the userform rather quickly by opening 2 instances of excel and copying and pasting working controls over and just rebuilding the broken ones. Thank you.